# Why do dictionaries not use capitalization in the beginning of their "sentences"?

Tags: capitalization, dictionaries

When I look up a dictionary, the example sentences always use small letters at the beginning of the sentence.

For examples:

> **exacerbate**
>
> **make** (a problem, bad situation, or negative feeling) worse: ***the** exorbitant cost of land in urban areas only exacerbated the problem* | ***the** forest fire was exacerbated by the lack of rain.*

Why not using capital letters in the first letter of "make", "the" and "the" above? Isn't it the rule of sentence?

Or it's just how dictionary does, so there is no need for an explanation?

Comment: Its online version of the entry is here: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/exacerbate. If you click "More example sentences", you will see some full sentences in the examples.

Comment: It's just a convention.  No need for an explanation.

Comment: You should correct your title: Why do dictionaries ... , not: Who do dictionaries ...

Comment: @CoffeDay please do not add the "grammar" tag to the posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot speak for all dictionaries, but the phrases the dictionary gave you **don't necessarily start a sentence**, so sentence caps are unnecessary. As JR said, the dictionary is showing an example **usage**, not an example *sentence*.

e.g.

> The fire lasted for four days; **the forest fire was exacerbated by the lack of rain.**

Comment: Exactly right; the dictionary is showing an example *usage,* not necessarily an example sentence. It could be part of a longer sentence: _Inflation was rampant, and the exorbitant cost of land in urban areas only exacerbated the problem_

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I don't mean to delve into this but I see no reason to downvote this answer.